# Best practices to build vendored code with CMake

Tags: cmake, dependencies, subproject, vendoring

I'm trying to understand what some of the best practices are when using modern CMake (3.13+) with respect to building and including vendored or submoduled code.

Say I'm building a library MyLib. My file structure is something like this

```
MyLib
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-src
|-include
|-submodules
 |-libgeos
```

In this example, I've included libgeos as a git submodule, because it's really convenient to be able to clone the project and immediately build and run tests because that dependency is present.  This could also be solved by using `FetchContent` or something, and my question still stands; the important thing is that I do not want to rely on libgeos being installed in build environment.

> Note I picked libgeos arbitrarily; I have no idea if libgeos is set up as a cmake project appropriately for this example, but this is all theoretical and I just needed some concrete library name. Please do not use the specific details of how libgeos is configured to answer this, unless libgeos is a good example of conventional cmake.

But now, there's some other project that wants to use my project, and it needs libgeos and doesn't want to depend on my project providing it.

```
OtherProject
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-src
|-include
|-submodules
 |-libgeos
 |-MyLib
  |submodules
  |-libgeos
```

When you clone OtherProject, you get two versions of libgeos, and maybe that's not great; but it's not a huge issue either. And maybe they're not the same version; say MyLib requires libgeos >= 2.0, so 2.0 is what MyLib includes, and OtherProject requires libgeos>=2.1 so OtherProject includes libgeos >= 2.1.

Now we potentially end up with some build issues. If we have the following line in `OtherProject/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(submodules/libgeos)
```

and then again, that same line within `MyLib/CMakeLists.txt`, we end up with cmake errors because `libgeos` as a target is defined twice in the build. This can be solved a couple of ways.

Check if geos exists before adding it

```
if(NOT TARGET geos)
  add_subdirectory(submodules/libgeos)
endif()
```

But this case has some issues; if that blob is in `OtherProject` at the top, it's fine and both projects use libgeos 2.1. But if it's in `OtherProject` *after* `add_subdirectory(submodules/MyLib)`, then the geos 2.0 version gets added to the build, which may or may not fail loudly (Hopefully it would).

This could also be solved with `find_package`. Both projects include `cmake/FindGeos.cmake` which use that blurb above (`if(NOT TARGET...)`) to add geos the build and then the top project cmake files can do this

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH cmake)
find_package(geos 2) # (or 2.1)
```

*then* it doesn't matter what order they try to include geos, because they will both defer to `FindGeos.cmake` in `OtherProject` because it's first in the module path.

But **now** there's a new issue, some ThirdProject wants to use MyLib also, but ThirdProject wants to depend on `libgeos` which is in the system environment. It uses `find_package(geos 2.1 CONFIG)` to use the installed `GeosConfig.cmake` file, which adds `geos::geos` to the build and sets `geos_FOUND`. Suddenly, MyLib fails to build, because `geos_FOUND` was set, but I'm doing `target_link_library(mylib PUBLIC geos)`.

So this *could* be solved by adding `add_library(geos::geos ALIAS geos)` in both custom `FindGeos.cmake` files, then it doesn't matter if geos was built from source or using the installed version, the target names are the same either way.

Now we get to my actual questions:
Lets start with

1. Am I crazy, no one does this, and my team is trying to use cmake all wrong?
2. Is there some feature of cmake that I've just completely missed that solves all these problems?
3. I suspect there's a good few books or presentations that cover this topic, but I just don't know where to look because there's *so many*; what should I be looking at? I've seen the [CMake Packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) page, which looks like it solves the problem when you're using all projects which are configured according to that page; but it doesn't really answer how to bridge the gap between older and newer projects.

If I'm not crazy and there's no straightforward answer or presentation that I can look at, then

4. What should the cmake configuration for both MyLib and libgeos look like so that these cases work?

- MyLib is built alone
- MyLib is built as part of a larger project which provides a different version of geos
- MyLib is built as part of a larger project which depends on a different version of geos in the environment

I understand that cmake provides helpers that could be used to produce `MyLibConfig.cmake` if I wanted to install it in the environment. I also see that the `export()` function exists, which could be used to save those files in the build tree somewhere and then find them with `find_package` in config mode. But this feels a bit odd to me to do because it's not a multi-stage build, it's just one invocation of `cmake` then `make`.

But lets say that's the right answer and the CMake for `libgeos` doesn't follow it. Would it be appropriate to have `FindGeos.cmake` do something like this?

```
if(NOT geos_FOUND)
    add_subdirectory(submodules/libgeos)
    export(geos NAMESPACE geos)
    find_package(geos CONFIG)
endif()
```

Comment: https://github.com/cginternals/cmake-init

Comment: I had not seen this before; so thank you for the link. However, it is explicitly not handling the case I'm caring about; it writes it off with 

"Actual solution: treat each project separately and use explicit dependency management."

So I guess are you implying that the answer is 'you're being dumb, don't do that, use conan (or whatever) instead'?

Comment: Your question is very big and elaborate - I wanted to hint at the "best-practices" part. I believe your question is too broad for this forum. As I'm struggling with properly exporting my projects, and I'm not enjoying particular CMake multi-dependency-project management, I do not want to vote to close your question, as I'm interested, but all I can imply is that I see that part of CMake currently as chaos under development. Use `find_package` for installed stuff, `add_subdirectory` for stuff you want to compile, but just not all stuff supports one method or the other and it's chaos.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I do think there's a place for using `find_package` for vendored things you might want to compile, but I agree that in general the rule you put forward in this comment makes sense. I suspect the real answer is probably something like 'just use conan'